# GWT-OpenLayers: Highlighting points with different styles on a layer

Tags: gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I have several points on a layer and all might have different styles associated with them. So I'm doing

```
VectorFeature pointFeature = new VectorFeature(point,pointStyle)
```

It all works fine until I do the select(i.e. click the point). When I do a select, the points are not highlighting. The point highlighlights if I remove the *pointStyle* from the `VectorFeature`, i.e.,

```
VectorFeature pointFeature = new VectorFeature(point)
```

I tried using `StyleMap` on  the layer but ended up getting the same result.

What could possibly be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you used the 'select' part of the styleMap?

var sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    'default': sty,
    'select': { strokeColor: "red", fillColor: "red" },
    'delete': { strokeOpacity: "0.2" }
});

I don't get your problem, could you, pls, provide a jsfiddle example? Because I use styling and selecting all the time and had no problem ever...

Comment: @Mochi I'm sorry. I'm not into js. I use a java wrapper for using OpenLayers. I can still provide you the outline for my problem. And yes, I used the `select` part of `StyleMap`. I'm using a StyleMap for the layer. But later I'm adding points to the layer which have different styles(colors). The points are getting rendered with the updated style(as expected,with different styles) but when I select the point its not highlighting. In short, I have a single layer with several point of different color which do not highlight on click.